# Apache CXF: Duplicate default namespace declaration

Tags: java, xml, soap, cxf

I'm having a problem with Apache CXF. Basically, it's turning this:

```
<consStatServ xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
```

Into this:

```
<consStatServ xmlns:ns2="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2" xmlns="" xmlns="" xmlns:ns5="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
```

Causing an "Duplicate default namespace declaration" exception.

This is my Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/core 
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

<jaxws:client id="nfeStatusServicoMGWebService"
    serviceClass="com.ats.nfe.webservice.mg.NfeStatusServico2Soap12"
    address="https://hnfe.fazenda.mg.gov.br/nfe2/services/NfeStatus2">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor">
        </bean>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor">
        </bean>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>


<http:conduit
    name="{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2}NfeStatusServico2Soap12Port.http-conduit">

    <http:tlsClientParameters>
        <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="123456"
                file="C:/Documents and Settings/HaroldoOliveira/teste.jks" />
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="123456"
                file="C:/Documents and Settings/HaroldoOliveira/truststore_nfe.jks" />
        </sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <!-- these filters ensure that a ciphersuite with export-suitable or 
                null encryption is used, but exclude anonymous Diffie-Hellman key change 
                as this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks -->
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
        </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" />

</http:conduit>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

And this is my test code:

```
public class NFeCXFTest {

private static String XML_TESTE_STATUS =
    "<consStatServ xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\" versao=\"2.00\">" +
    "    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>" +
    "    <cUF>31</cUF>" +
    "    <xServ>STATUS</xServ>" +
    "</consStatServ>";


private NfeStatusServico2Soap12 statusServ;

@Test
public void commitNfeStatusServicoNF() {
    NfeCabecMsg cabec = new NfeCabecMsg();
    cabec.setCUF("31");
    cabec.setVersaoDados("2.00");

    NfeDadosMsg dados = new NfeDadosMsg();
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(XML_TESTE_STATUS));
        Document contentDoc = db.parse(is);
        dados.getContent().add(contentDoc.getDocumentElement());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Erro ao empacotar o conteúdo, ", e);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Erro ao empacotar o conteúdo, ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Erro ao empacotar o conteúdo, ", e);
    }           

    NfeStatusServicoNF2Result ret = this.statusServ.nfeStatusServicoNF2(dados, cabec);
    Object retVal = ret.getContent().iterator().next();
    System.out.println(retVal.getClass());
    System.out.println("***.***.***");

    try {
        Result stringResult = new StringResult();
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource((Node)retVal), stringResult);
        System.out.println("O retorno é: " + stringResult);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Impossível gerar nova requisição, ", e);
    }
}

@Resource(name="nfeStatusServicoMGWebService")
public void setStatusServ(NfeStatusServico2Soap12 statusServ) {
    this.statusServ = statusServ;
}
```

}

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to normalize the document prior to invoking the service:

Document.normalizeDocument()

I have seen issues with CXF not properly serializing the message and I have used the CXF transformer feature to modify the message.  Give it a try:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html